# json object append in redis-cli

Tags: json, redis, redis-cli, redisjson

i am using **redis-cli** for one of my project and i need to append the data into existing json in redis, i have tried **json.arrappend** but it is not working.
i need to append in sDetail array and in jsonDetails array. **any suggestions** how to append in json in redis-cli

```
'{"xyz": [{"subType": 1,"sDetail": [{"eCs": "3","jsonDetails": "{\"ce\" :[{\"cRId\":272, \"cV\":10000, \"type\":1, \"tId\":0, \"uTid\":\"T00005\", \"sNumber\":\"53320\", \"sDetailId\":1101}]}"}]}]}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonDetails` is a string and not an array

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET test $ '{"xyz": [{"subType": 1,"sDetail": [{"eCs": "3","jsonDetails": "{\"ce\" :[{\"cRId\":272, \"cV\":10000, \"type\":1, \"tId\":0, \"uTid\":\"T00005\", \"sNumber\":\"53320\", \"sDetailId\":1101}]}"}]}]}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.TYPE test $.xyz[0].sDetail[0].jsonDetails
1) "string"
```

If you set it like this

```
JSON.SET test $ '{"xyz": [{"subType": 1,"sDetail": [{"eCs": "3","jsonDetails": {"ce" :[{"cRId":272, "cV":10000, "type":1, "tId":0, "uTid":"T00005", "sNumber":"53320", "sDetailId":1101}]}}]}]}'
```

It would be an array

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.TYPE test $.xyz[0].sDetail[0].jsonDetails.ce
1) "array"
```

And now you can append to it using `JSON.ARRAPPEND`, for example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.ARRAPPEND test $.xyz[0].sDetail[0].jsonDetails.ce '{"new": "data"}'
1) (integer) 2
```

To append to `sDetail` you can try something like

```
JSON.ARRAPPEND test $.xyz[0].sDetail '{"eCs": "42", "jsonDetails": {"ce": [{"cRId":999, "cV": 888}]}}'
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379> json.type test >>
object ...
this json type is object that's why i am getting error *ERR Search path error at offset 1: an identifier can only begin with a letter, a dollar sign or an underscore - use bracket notation for anything else* any suggestions on that...

Comment: @AbhishekChhabra Can you please share the path you are trying to use?